# OpenGL - How to track a moving object?

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to learn how I can track a moving object in OpenGL. The position of the object will be a continuous input. Also, what if when the object moves out of the screen?

Comment: Take a look at gluLookAt()

Answer (score 5):

You have to position and orient your **camera** towards the object. That means you will have to provide the correct **View Matrix**.

You can use functions such as [`gluLookAt()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) to generate a View Matrix that points towards a specific object.

If you don't know what a view matrix is, I suggest looking at this tutorial (http://learnopengl.com). Check out [this page](http://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Camera) which explains cameras matrices work in openGL